# how to solve this java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in java code?

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

there is one error occur on this line i did not understand what to say this. and there is also i am use one library of qoppa.jar how to slove this issue can any one help me

```
    m_LoadedDoc = new PDFDocument(new FilePDFSource((String) path[0]), PDFViewer.this);




    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.qoppa.android.pdfViewer.e.p.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.qoppa.android.pdfProcess.PDFDocument.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.pdfplugin.PDFViewer$LoadDocument.doInBackground(PDFViewer.java:469)
```

Comment: Can you log  path[0] to see the full path? It may be empty or a relative path to the file.

Comment: yes path is correct come there..

Comment: And what is it? Does the file exist there? Have you tried with another file?

Comment: yes there is available file path is like  "/sdcard/sample.pdf"

Comment: i am try with is. it also same error occur    m_LoadedDoc = new PDFDocument(new InputStreamPDFSource((InputStream) path[0]), PDFViewer.this);

Comment: Is this the only exception you have. There should be at least one more.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: Have you solved this issue ? am getting the same with qoppa.jar

Comment: do't use this qoppa.jar becasue it's give watermark. so it's not proper. i have done all project suessfull but in last i got watermark so it not proper

Answer (score 0):

There is a magic line that needs to be called before reading the document:

```java
// Magic: Register asset manager for font loading.
StandardFontTF.mAssetMgr = getContext().getAssets();

// Now you can read the document.
PDFDocument doc = new PDFDocument(new FilePDFSource(path), PDFViewer.this);
```

You might also need to include the `assets/fonts` and `assets/cmaps` directories from the sample project.